# Product catalog API

Tags: database

What is the common practice in creating (and updating) the product catalog (all products/models/tech specs) for online electronics store?

Does any of the manufacturers/OEMs have an appropriate API to pull the data?

Thanks,
sbereli

Comment: Which one in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are obviously ton's of ways to do this.  However, if you are looking for something for a large scale enterprise project, then you probably want to look into a Product Information Management (PIM) solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_information_management.

Also, within that there is the Open ICEcat, which is an open catalog management infrastructure.  Find out more here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_ICEcat. This format allows for APIs that can be used to pull data from manufacturer's.  Unfortunately, I don't believe many companies use this software but I could be incorrect.

If this is not what you are looking for, could you please be more clear and give us some more detail and maybe an example of what you mean?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I actually found the ICECat catalogs, and a list of PIM vendors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then vote me up and mark me as correct ;-)